# How to search text only in selected records using sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

How can i search text in selected records, not in all records of the model?

```
nodes_res = Node.where(id: ids)
search = nodes_res.search { keywords "query" }
```

but sunspot searches in all records of the model :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested this but it looks you you want https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot#scoping-scalar-fields

See this example:

```
# Posts with a category of 1, 3, or 5
Post.search do
  with(:category_ids, [1, 3, 5])
end
```

So something like this:

```
Node.search do
  keywords "query"
  with(:ids, [ids])
end
```